# I got an error when add two buttons to the right of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action
        , target: self, action: #selector(tapButton))


    let addButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add
        , target: self, action: #selector(tapButton1))

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [addButton,addButton1]

}

@IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any){
    print("your tap")
    let shareText = "share to others"

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: nil)

    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
@IBAction func tapButton1(_ sender: Any){
    print("your tap1")

}
```

I got an error

> Cannot assign the value of type '[UIBarButtonItem]' to type
>   'UIBarButtonItem?'" in this line " navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
>   [addButton,addButton1]

What's the problem?

Comment: `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` That's singular, not plural. So it can accept only one, not two (in an array). You meant `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =[addButton, addButton1]`.

Comment: Replace `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`  to `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`

Comment: Oh, I fixed it, thank you so much, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addButton,addButton1]
```